# Has OPC-UA a connection timeout?

Tags: qt, opc-ua, qtopcua

I notice that any OpcUa application I use on our plant get frequent disconnections every few minutes. It happens with my Qt console application, with the [OpcUaViewer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtopcua-opcuaviewer-example.html) example and even with another viewer I found online (I don't recall the name right now - I'll update the question!).

When the disconnection happens I catch the signals for `errorChanged` and `stateChanged`:

```
QOpcUaClient::ConnectionError
QOpcUaClient::Disconnected
```

Please note I have several variables with monitoring enable.
Then I can successfully reconnect, but I wonder why this happens.
The PLCs and the server are on the same wired LAN.
It happens with different kind of machines (different manufacturer) but it happens with OpcUa *only*.

We have other machines on the same LAN that uses other TCP protocols and they don't have this issue. I guess it's not a networking problem, then.

Is there any timeout settings I need to tweak client side?